# Execution part of an infinite list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm a little confused about how exactly Haskell execution works on infinite lists. for example, consider below `sum` function :

```
sum (takeWhile (<10000) (filter odd (map (^2) [1..])))
```

here the code for finding Sum of all odd squares that are smaller than `10000`  and I know how these `takewhile`, `filter`, `map` functions work. my doubt is, here the `map` function is taking one element from the infinite list and squaring it and returning the list of squared elements to the `filter` function right? in that case it would run infinitely for squaring that infinite list of elements isn't it? or is it taking just one element squaring it and then returning to the `filter`?

Comment: The fact that Haskell has infinite lists should probably mean that it is possible to do *something* with them, right? Otherwise they would be pretty useless.

Answer (score 7):

Haskell is as lazy as it can possibly be. It doesn't calculate any value that you don't ask it for, and if you do `let nums = filter odd (map (^2) [1..])` you haven't forced it to calculate anything yet. For now it knows that `nums` is of type `Num a => [a]` (because of the types of the operations you've described) but it doesn't know anything else about it (and that's fine!)

Even when you run `takeWhile (<10000)` you're not forcing any numbers. Now ghc knows that `takeWhile (<10000) nums` has type `(Ord a, Num a) => [a]` (you've introduced the additional typeclass when you compared by `(<)`) but that's all it knows.

**Even** once you call `sum`, ghc doesn't have to do anything. `sum` expects a `Num a => [a]` (technically a `(Num a, Foldable t) => t a` but let's pretend those are the same thing for right now) and you've given it one. Until you actually ask for the result of that operation, ghc doesn't do *anything*. You can test this by doing `let foobar = sum [1..]` in your interpreter. As long as you don't ever ask for the result of `foobar`, Haskell is fine with that expression.

However, if you ever ask for that result, you've forced the whole line to compute. `sum` needs its list, so it asks `takeWhile (<10000)` for it. `takeWhile` needs its list, so it asks `filter odd` for it. `filter` needs its list so it asks `map (^2)` for it, but `filter` doesn't need the whole list at a time, so `map` still works as lazily as possible and gives each number one at a time.

Once `takeWhile` has found a number `(>=10000)`, it doesn't need anymore and happily hands off to `sum`, which produces your result and ghc goes back to being lazy, not producing any more results of `nums` unless you need them.

Comment: such a clever lazy language . i loved it .thank you @Adam

Comment: Great explanation. It works for list comprehension as well `sum (takeWhile (<10000) [x^2 | x <- [1..], odd (x^2)])` however evaluation fails for `sum [x^2 | x <- [1..], odd (x^2), x^2 < 10000]`.

Answer (score 3):

`takeWhile (<10000)` puts a limit on how many elements to process for the sum. Haskell is lazy-evaluated and will only do as much work as needed.  For this reason it's a common pattern to create an infinite list and limit it with a take operation.  This means that only elements from a list that are used are generated and processed. Once `takeWhile`s condition is false, no other elements from the list are used, so they aren't generated.

Answer (score 3):

You can imagine a dialogue between functions.

`GHCi` asks `sum` to give a result. `sum` wakes up and asks `takeWhile` to give at least one element. Wakes up `takeWhile` and asks `filter` to give at least one element. Wakes up `filter` and asks `map` to give at least one element. Wakes up `map` and asks `[1..]` to give at least one element.

`[1..]` gives `1`. `map` applies `(^2)` and gives `(1^2)`. `filter` checks `odd (1^2)` and gives `1`. `takeWhile` checks (1 < 10000) and gives `1`. `sum` adds `1` to accumulator and continue asks `takeWhile` to give at least one element. And so on, until the `takeWhile` check is successful. Then `sum` returns the accumulator to GHCi.